# How to live-update an input prompt in python3 (preferrably without (n)curses)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, stdout, stdin

I want to have a live-updating input prompt which.. changes lol
I cannot think of a good way to it unless I manually `getch()` and print
every character myself, would be nice if there's a more proper way
to do it

Here's an example of how I want to do it

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Example: reading input and updating the prompt
Dependencies:
    - getch <https://pypi.org/project/getch/>"""


import sys
from warnings import filterwarnings as filter_warnings

from getch import getch  # type: ignore


def main() -> int:
    """Entry/main function"""

    s: str = ""

    while True:
        sys.stdout.write(f"\33[2K\r{len(s)}: {s}")
        sys.stdout.flush()

        c: str = getch()

        if c == "\x7f":
            s = s[:-1]
        elif c in ("\n", "\r", "\r\n", "\x04"):
            break
        else:
            # Debug:
            # print(ord(c), repr(chr(ord(c))))

            s += c

    print(f"\nValue: {s}\n")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    assert main.__annotations__.get("return") is int, "main() should return an integer"

    filter_warnings("error", category=Warning)
    sys.exit(main())
```

> I almost got the example fully working for myself, if this question gets answered I'll just release it on pypi or something after full cleanup and implementation: [Carriage return failing on wrapped lines in a linux terminal python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74000877/carriage-return-failing-on-wrapped-lines-in-a-linux-terminal-python3)

Any way to do this properly?

Here's some pseudo code:

```py
hello = editable_input("prompt: ")
x = 0

while not hello.done():
    sleep(1)
    hello.set_prompt(f"Hello {x}: ")
    x += 1
```

And it'd look something like this

Opening:

```
prompt:
```

(user starts typing something)

1st second:

```
Hello 0: he
```

2nd second:

```
Hello 1: hell
```

3rd second:

```
Hello 2: hello wo
```

4th second:

```
Hello 3: hello world
```

and so on

Comment: By the way, if using getch and managing it manually is the only way please tell me because I don't want to start work on it if I don't fully know it

Comment: Are you just looking for the built in `input()` function? I'm not quite following what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Is [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) basically what you're looking for?

Comment: @HampusLarsson I am looking for input() but a tyoe if it where I could update the prompt live and yeah i know of curses but is there any other way to do it?

Comment: An example of what you want the code to do would go a long way here, because built-in function `input()` already does exactly what you write that you want to do. An example would explain WHY that function will not work for you.

Comment: @HampusLarsson it does not, `input()` has a static prompt, okay, for example, I want the prompt to be the current time and I want for it to update **while** the user is typing something, the `input()` function can only have one prompt update and it's on the call, like `input("hello: ")` and you can't change that hello anymore

Comment: @HampusLarsson I added some pseudocode in the question

Comment: @HampusLarsson I also added an example, but I want a more proper way to do it

Comment: I almost got the example fully working for myself, if this question gets answered I'll just release it on pypi or something after full cleanup and implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74000877/carriage-return-failing-on-wrapped-lines-in-a-linux-terminal-python3